# Проблема в создании каталогов относительно директории запускаемого приложения

Tags: c++, winapi

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь создать каталог функцией SHCreateDerectoryExA(); относительно директории запускаемого приложения: пока безуспешно. Таким образом, всё думал и думал, в чем же проблема.

```
string str_log_dir     ( "..\\user\\log\\" );
SHCreateDerectoryExA   ( NULL, str_log_gir.c_str(), NULL );
```

ShlObj.h к проекту подключил. Да и вряд ли здесь проблема в преобразовании string to const char *. Как видете, точки не помогают, даже здесь. А ведь при создании одиночного файла через fstream, например, ".\test_file.txt", такая фишка прокатывает. WinAPI, как я вижу не работает с этим. Или я чего-то не знаю.

```
fstream log_file;
log_file.open( ".\\engine.log", ios::binary, ios::out );
```

Каталог при запуске exe-шника не создаётся, а вот файл - пожалуйста. В любом случае, я надеюсь, что ясно описал свои незнания в WinAPI, или как ещё такое можно назвать. Прошу помочь, часа 2 сижу, гуглю, да всё без толку.

Comment: Зачем SHCreateDerectoryEx, если есть CreateDirectory? Ну и стандартное правило: если функция не работает - смотрите в MSDN что написано про получение кода ошибки.

Comment: Затем, Владимир, что CreateDirectory не работает со вложенными каталогами.

Comment: Код ошибки покажите

Comment: Вам не должно хотеться по Windows создать каталог в подкаталоге относительно приложения. Взрослые программы находятся в защищённом от записи каталоге, наподобие Program Files. По вашей проблеме: проверьте ваш _текущий_ каталог.

Comment: Каталог я проверял. Всё в порядке, только вот почему-то заданные директории при запуске этой же самой программы не создаются. А тема взрослых прог в этом случае не важна: это мой тест по file system. Файлы, каталоги, расширения и т.п.

Answer (score 2):

В примечаниях к [функции](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762131%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> ERROR_BAD_PATHNAME: The pszPath parameter was set to a relative path.

Так что не пользуйтесь относительным путем...

Comment: Не создан. Эта функция как раз должна создать его, предположительно. Если бэскслеш убрать, компилятор выдаст предупреждение: неизвестная escape-последовательность.

Comment: Да, главная проблема в том, что эта функция *не работает с относительными путями*. Преобразуйте программно относительный путь в абсолютный. Тогда съедает всё.

Comment: Всем спасибо. Кажется получилось, сложнее, но всё же.